# Calling an external script from Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I have a Django admin interface that is used almost solely as a gui form for making changes to a single postgresql table. There's also a Python script that's currently run manually from the command line whenever a change is made to the database, & I'd like to hook that up so it runs whenever someone hits "save" after making a change to a row of the table via the admin interface. If this was an entry in views.py, it looks like I'd import the script as a module and run its main function from the view (ie, [Can Django use "external" python scripts linked to other libraries (NumPy, RPy2...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776515/can-django-use-external-python-scripts-linked-to-other-libraries-numpy-rpy2)). I'm not sure, however, how to do this in the admin interface.

- How is admin.py similar/different to a regular entry in views.py?
- Where do I put the import/call to the external script - somewhere in the model, somewhere in admin.py?

I'm familiar with Python, but am fairly new to (& somewhat mystified by) "web stuff" (ie, frameworks like Django), & I'm not even sure if I'm asking this question very clearly, because I'm still a little fuzzy on the view/model concept ...

**Edit:** Turns out I had, in fact, found the solution by reading the documentation/tutorial, but assumed there was a difference with admin stuff. As Keith mentioned in the comments, I'm now running into permissions issues, but I guess that's a separate problem. So thanks, & maybe I'll stop second guessing myself ...

Comment: "...runs whenever someone hits "save"...".  Why aren't you using the model's `save()` method for this?

Comment: It can, but you may also run into permission problems since the webserver runs as another user. Have you tried just incorporating the necessary Python code into the handler?

Comment: @S.Lott - I don't see a save() method defined in the model, is it implicit? I'm not entirely sure what happens under the hood when a user hits the save button in the gui, frankly ... like I said, very new to Django.

Comment: @Beekguk: Please do the **entire** Django tutorial.  It's in there.  You'll see how it works.

Comment: @Keith - the script that needs to run is sort of an administrative tool that calls a bunch of other things - scripts that archive old files, ones that send various notifications, etc. So that particular code could get incorporated into the handler, but I want to avoid messing with the rest of it if I possibly can. I'm not sure how I'd do that, in any case.

Comment: @S.Lott - Sigh. I did. And like after most tutorials, I now know - kinda - how to set up a shiny new project, but messing around with an inherited less-than-well-put-together legacy application that I really don't want to break is another matter. But I'll go dig for the info some more.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward.  Documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, things you want to happen at 'save' time are either

1. Part of the model.

   If so, you override the model's `save` method: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

   You can do **anything** in that `save` method.
2. Part of the view function.

   If so, you either extend the admin interface (not so easy), or you write your own.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might consider is defining the save_model method in your ModelAdmin.  This will get executed when someone saves from the admin (but not when someone does a save outside of the admin).  This approach might depend on what your requirements are, but should give you the necessary hook when doing the save from the admin.

In admin.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = models.MyModel

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        # you can put custom code in here
        obj.save()
```